# Merging two lists of different objects into one. C# Unity2D

Tags: c#, list, unity-game-engine

First I want to give some context. I got two different classes (class Player and class Enemy), each class contains different data, but they both hold the value "int Initiative".

```
public class Enemy : MonoBehaviour 
{

    public int initiative;
    //More code

}
public class Player : MonoBehaviour 
{

    public int initiative;
    //More code
 }
```

On my project I have several units from both classes and they are stored on 2 different lists of objects

```
private List<Player> players;                           
private List<Enemy> enemies;

void Awake()
{
    players = new List<Player>();
    enemies = new List<Enemy>();
}
```

Is not shown in the code, but each unit is being sent and storaged on those list depending on their class.

Now my question:

Is there any way of combining both list into a single list keeping all the different objects? (I tried to do this, but didn't get far)

If there is no way of combining both lists because they contain different types of objects, could I create a single list that only storage the int initiative, type of object as well as the position on their previous list? (so I can refer to the lists (players and enemies) when needed. Please explain me how I could achieve this (if possible with some code).

With this I am trying to create some sort of system that will look at the initiative of each unit and call them in order starting for the one that has the highest.

Please I am pretty new in C# and coding in general, so excuse me if the question is too simple, or doesn't make sense.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Store it in List<MonoBehaviour> collection

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
public class MonoBehaviour 
{
    public int initiative;//Since you are using inheritance this can be set here
}
public class Enemy : MonoBehaviour 
{
    //More code
}
public class Player : MonoBehaviour 
{
    //More code
}
```

Here is the code to merge them into one list:

```
List<MonoBehaviour> list = new List<MonoBehaviour>()
list.Add(new Enemy());
list.Add(new Player());
```

When you want to process them differently somewhere for example you create a method as below:

```
void ProcessList(List<MonoBehaviour> list)
{
    foreach(var l in list)
    {
        if(l is Enemy)
        {
            var enemy = (Enemy) l;
            //process the enemy
        }
        else
        {
            var player = (Player) l;
            //process as a player
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use inheritance. Having base for both `Enemy` and `Player`.

```
public class AliveEntity
{ 
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public double HP {get;set;}
}
public class Player : AliveEntity
{ /*...*/ }
public class Enemy : AliveEntity
{ /*...*/ }
```

And then the list could be `List<AliveEntity>`.